# I'm trying to use 'echo' inside body

Tags: php, html

when i run php code inside the  tag, i'm expecting the 'echo' to echo inside the  tag, but it doesn't, instead it prints what i'm 'echoing' before

i've already moved around the code, and fixed everything i know, it still doesnt work

"dbh.inc.php"

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "hayleyblog";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
  echo "<p>connected</p>";
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require "dbh.inc.php";
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
$conn
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

i expect 'connected' to be printed inside the body tag, but instead its printed before the html tag,

Comment: change `echo "<p>connected</p>";` to `$conn = "<p>connected</p>";` in your `else` and then `echo $conn;` in your HTML

Comment: He would also need to `echo $conn;`

Comment: i have checked this in my system.it is working fine. may be there could anything missing in you database name or username something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should store value in variable instead of echo when check connection.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "hayleyblog";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
  $conn = "<p>connected</p>";
}
```

**Then you can echo as below.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require "dbh.inc.php";
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>


 <?php
   echo $conn;
    ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

please understand the concept of include which helps you move ahead in PHP.
where you include your file its work like

PHP include statement adds your other file code add one current file where your include statement attach.

your file included means your code is there ultimately

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "hayleyblog";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);
$connection_status="";

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
} else {      
  $connection_status = "<p>connected</p>";
}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require "dbh.inc.php";
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
echo $connection_status;
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

try this I hope you understand if any query please ask me in in a comment I can explain you in detail. you should understand the concept in depth about PHP include statement.
thanks

Comment: no i understood what "include 'file.php', " meant, and im self taught in php, i learned at it at 13 and just got back into it, but thanks for the help, always happy to see things from another's point of view